# Quarkus Flyway Externalized Init existing with non-zero exit code

Tags: quarkus, flyway

I am using Quarkus with Flyway, using externalized init meaning that I am running the quarkus container with QUARKUS_INIT_AND_EXIT first, before running the actual runtime containers. The runs flyway and then exists.  I am doing this with a job created by helm with a pre-upgrade hook.

However, the container exists with 1 instead of 0, so helm thinks it is failing. Best I can tell, the flyway migration is successful, so I can't figure out why quarkus is exiting with 1.

```
2023-10-11T14:41:56.805 D [main] io.quarkus.runtime.Application   Shutting down with exit code 1
```

My guess is that since there are no new migrations to apply (the database is already up-to-date) that might be the reason, but hard to tell from the logs.

Any ideas to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what's wrong but let's try to figure this out.

When `QUARKUS_INIT_AND_EXIST` is used, the exit code used by Quarkus is 0.
The expected output should be:

`2023-10-12 07:29:00,045 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) hello-world stopped in 0.001s`

Flyway, itself should not have an issue even if no new migrations are available.

So, I am guessing that the issue lies else where.

You could possibly change your logging settings to see if we can squeeze more info out of it: https://quarkus.io/guides/logging

And you could try to run debug it locally using something like:
`QUARKUS_INIT_AND_EXIT=true java -jar target/quarkus-app/quarkus-run.jar`

Answer (score 0):

My issue was apparently not related to flyway itself, but adding the following helped to get quarkus to return 0 appropriately.

```
MP_JWT_VERIFY_ISSUER=none
MP_JWT_VERIFY_PUBLICKEY_LOCATION=none
QUARKUS_HIBERNATE_ORM_ACTIVE=false
```

The first two made it work, and disabling ORM made it a bit faster as well.